# SIM808 GSM+GPS module sleep and power usage?

Tags: arduino, gsm

I'm using a SIM808 GSM+GPS module on a LoNet breakout board: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/LoNet_-_GSM/GPRS/GPS_Breakout with an Adafruit Trinket Pro 3V, and everything works.

I've taken care to build in power save modes in my application. I can enable the SIM808 slow clock, so it can sleep with DTR=1, which I call "light sleep" mode. Also there is a "deep sleep" mode, where I set AT+CFUN=0 to further decrease functionality of the SIM808, and power usage. (During deep sleep the RF circuits are off, so no SMS reception..)

I've measured power consumption by measuring the voltage across a 1 ohm resistor in series with the battery.

During normal GSM operation 19-20 mA is used; with slow clock enabled also 19-20 mA, in deep sleep 18-19 mA.

Switching on GPS makes the board use 43-44 mA. I see no difference while acquiring the GPS fix, or when a fix is reached. The wiki page (above) says that continuous tracking takes 24 mA, but apparently that is on top of the 20 mA when just the GSM is used. Indeed 20+24 is 44 mA, the value I measure.

I'm quite disappointed that the sleep conditions don't seem to save any power!

Should I do things like remove the green power LED? The design drawing shows a 470 ohm R in series, so that could save ca 8 mA?

The board does have a battery charging circuit; could that be responsible for the 20 mA  base current? When I power down the SIM808 only ca 0.02 mA is used, so I wonder if there is an external circuit responsible for the 20 mA  base current. The SIM808 Hardware Docs spec a power consumption of around 1 mA only! - I wish!

Comment: Using the same Lonet module I've tried removing the green led, I see around 15mA during normal GSM operation and between 40-50mA with the GPS module turned on. And the DTR power saving doesn't save any power for me either

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem like you but on [another board](https://www.eprolabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WLC-0019_2.jpg).
As you can see at the top of the board below the right one of the two SMA connectors it says: "Active GPS Antenna". And thats the solution to the problem.

When I disconnected the GPS antenna the current dropped to ~670µA without LEDs and when slowclock (AT+CSCLK=1) was enabled, AT+CFUN=0 and DTR pin was high (eg. 3.3V).

So if you want to really make your SIM808 module low power you have to switch the active GPS antenna off with a PMOS.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffPzT.jpg) shows the active GPS antenna circuit of my SIM808 Module.

EDIT:

Damn I don't know how to delete or edit a comment... And I can't post more than 2 links, please go to the next links by yourself:

This wiki page (wiki.seeedstudio.com/wiki/LoNet_-_GSM/GPRS/GPS_Breakout) of the LoNet states that: "GPS Antenna: this is an uFL GPS antenna connector. You can connect either passive or active GPS antenna to it. Active GPS antenna runs at 2.8V voltage."

And the schematic (wiki.seeedstudio.com/images/3/37/LoNet_808_Schematic.pdf) shows in the top right corner, that the GPS connector is prepared for an active antenna (the inductor in series with the current limiting resistor).
So if you don't have an active antenna you maybe can just cut the trace between the inductor and the GPS connector.

I don't know what will happen when you are using a passive antenna, you have to try it yourself.
Good luck!

Comment: Good find! This may very well be it. So it's simply the GPS antenna that uses power, and that power is not switched off by the SIM808? The board should include that switch?

Comment: Hmm, according to https://www.seeedstudio.com/LoNet-808-Mini-GSMGPRS-GPS-Breakout-p-2493.html# the GPS antenna is not an active but a passive antenna. The circuit you have drawn is for an active antenna! 

My board is currently elsewhere, I'll check in a few weeks if disconnecting the GPS antenna saves power!

Comment: In the schematic it says "Only used for active GPS antenna" and two connectors, ANT1 and ANT2. Not sure if that is the same connector. Are the 22Ω R and the 22nH L on the board?

Comment: ANT2 is the GSM connector. When I take a look at google pictures of LoNet 808 then I can see two 0402 components near the GPS connector - they seem to be assembled on every LoNet. This [top layer view](https://aisler.net/yhyuan/eagle/lonet-808) says that they are indeed the 22Ohm and 22nH coil.

Comment: Ok! I think you are right. They should have provided an off-switch for the antenna. The way it is now a current us drawn through the R and L whether you use an active antenna or not?